# how do I get percentages of classes in a classified image?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, classification

I am using ArcMap 10.3

I have two layers, one classified raster, Landsat based dNBR, where classes show burn severity, and a shapefile containing polygons, drawn based on the dNBR image and that shows the extent of the burned areas (to have the area)

I need the percentages of the burn severity classes inside the polygons. 
for example: 
- low burn = X%
- medium = Y%
- high = Z%

but considering that the total area is the area of the polygons and not the whole image.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Tabulate area in arcgis spatial analyst

Comment: I am using arcmap 10.3